# capturar el valor de una celda para ser calculada en un datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, datatable

espero me puedan ayudar. Soy nuevo en el desarrollo web. El caso es el siguiente:

Estoy desarrollando una pantalla de definición de lista de precios, la cual es una consulta que muestro en un datatable con la siguiente estructura:

**Código - Nombre - Iva - Precio Neto - Precio Total (*iva)- (Botón agregar precio)**

la idea es que por cada registro, el campo precio neto tenga una caja de texto en la cual se digite el valor y de acuerdo al iva que tenga el producto se calcule  y se muestre en la celda precio total(precioneto*iva). Para esto, en el controlador agrego la caja d texto al datatable de la siguiente manera:

```
    $datos=$referencia->get_tar_iva();
    $data=Array();
    foreach($datos as $row){
    $sub_array=array();
    $sub_array[]=$row["cod_ref"];
    $sub_array[]=$row["nom_ref"];
    $sub_array[]=$row["tarifa"];
    $sub_array[]='<input type="number" ></input>'; 
    $sub_array[]='<button type="button" onClick="guardaprecio" id="guardaprecio" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-icon"><div><i class="fa fa-edit"></div></button>';
    $data[]=$sub_array;
    }
    $results=array(
        "sEcho"=>1,
        "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),
        "aaData"=>$data);
    echo json_encode($results);
```

/////////

Luego en la vista tengo el datatable de la siguiente manera:

```
<table id="ref_lista" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full">
     
                                    <th style="width: 15%;">Cod_Ref</th>
                                    <th style="width: 25%;">Nombre</th>
                                    <th style="width: 15%;">Tar Iva</th>
                                    <th style="width: 10%;">Precio Neto</th> 
                                    <th style="width: 10%;">Precio+Iva</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%;"></th>
                                    
                                </tr>

                                
                            </thead>
```

y en el JS hago lo siguiente, cuando se da click en el boton guardarprecio:

///

```
$(document).on("click","#guardaprecio",function(){ 


  var fila=$( this ).closest('tr');
       iva=fila.find("td").eq(2).text();

      precioneto=fila.find("td").eq(3).text();
       total=parseFloat(iva)*parseFloat(precioneto);
        console.log(iva);
        console.log(precioneto);
        console.log(total);
});
```

El problema es que el valor del Iva si me lo muestra, pero el valor que digito en la caja de texto del precio neto, no, y esto hace que el calculo no se realice, mostrandome NaN.

Intente colocando una caja de texto por fuera del datatable y el valor digitado si me lo calcula con el valor del iva, pero realmente necesito digitarlo en el datatable y al dar enter se muestre elr esultado en la siguiente casilla.

Como puedo lograr que el valor digitado en la caja de texto si lo tome para poder hacer el calculo?

Agradezco mucho su colaboración.